# Wrong size when reading the content of an uploaded file

Tags: java, file-upload

I try to read the content of an uploaded file. The library I use is `gwtupload` which uses the `Apache FileUpload` library. The uploaded file is 22 bytes but when I read it with a `Scanner` or a `BufferedReader`, the last line takes a long time to parse. Here is my code snippet along with the execution result:

Code:

```
        for (FileItem item : sessionFiles) {
            System.out.println("FileItem.size() = " + item.getSize());
            // Read with a scanner
            System.out.println("Read with a Scanner");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(item.getInputStream());
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                sb.append(scanner.nextLine()).append("\n");
                System.out.println(sb.length());
            }
            // Read with a Reader
            System.out.println("Read with a Reader");
            StringBuffer sb2 = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(item.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb2.append(line).append("\n");
                System.out.println(sb2.length());
                // if (sb2.length() + 1 == item.getSize()) {
                // break;
                // }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%d: %c [%d]", i,
                        sb2.charAt(i), (int) sb2.charAt(i)));
            }
            System.out.println("End");
```

Result:

```
FileItem.size() = 22
Read with a Scanner
21
1047552
Read with a Reader
21
1047552
0: I [73]
1: d [100]
2: , [44]
3: D [68]
4: a [97]
5: t [116]
6: e [101]
7: , [44]
8:   [32]
9: D [68]
10: e [101]
11: s [115]
12: c [99]
13: r [114]
14: i [105]
15: p [112]
16: t [116]
17: i [105]
18: o [111]
19: n [110]
20: 
 [10]
21:
```

The eclipse console displays the characters until 29 but when I paste the console, it stops to 21. From character 21 to 29 the `ASCII` code is `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is (I suspect) that the file you are reading is using `\r\n` as its line terminator.  Your code is assuming that the line terminator is one character.

A second problem is that your code is calculating the size in characters, but the size that you are checking against is (most likely) the size in bytes.  This will break if your file is encoded in an encoding scheme where a character may be represented by more than one byte; e.g. UTF-8.

A final problem is that you are using the platform's default character set to decode file.  But if you downloaded that file from a random server, it could be encoded in a different character set.

---

> The uploaded file comes from a Win 7 box but I don't think it should matter for a Scanner because it checks for all the possible line terminator.

You didn't understand what I said.  The problem is the following lines:

```
sb2.append(line).append("\n");
System.out.println(sb2.length())
```

These make the assumption that the length of a line termination used in the file is the same as the length of `"\n"`.  And this is **NOT TRUE** if the actual line termination is `"\r\n"` ... as it is likely to be when the file comes from Windows.

(Same code appears in both the Reader and Scanner parts.)

Comment: The uploaded file comes from a `Win 7` box but I don't think it should matter for a `Scanner` because it checks for all the possible line terminator. `private static final String LINE_SEPARATOR_PATTERN = "\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085]";` when using the `hasNextLine()` or `nextLine()` method.